# Why do I need to use mode = wb with download.file() for this .rds file?

Tags: r, download

I was getting hung up on [Shiny Apps Tutorial Lesson 5](http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson5/) because I was unable to open the `counties.rds` file.  `readRDS()` threw: `error reading from connection`.

I figured out I could open the `.rds` fine if I downloaded it with `download.file(URL, dest, mode = "wb")` or simply used my browser to download the file to my local directory.

**Outstanding Question:**  Why does the `counties.rds` file not open properly if I use `download.file()` without setting `mode = "wb"`?  I expect the answer will be something obvious like:  "Duh, `counties.rds` is a binary file."  However, before I try to answer my own question, I'd like confirmation from someone with more experience.

**Repro steps:**

```
    download.file("http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson5/census-app/data/counties.rds",
    "counties.rds")

    counties <- readRDS("counties.rds")
    Error in readRDS("counties.rds") : error reading from connection
```

**Resolution:**  Download via browser or use binary mode (`wb`).

```
    download.file("http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson5/census-app/data/counties.rds",
    "counties.rds", mode = "wb")
    counties <- readRDS("counties.rds") # Success!
```

Comment: Probably because an ".rds" file is not text but binary.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to always specify 'mode' regardless and that it pretty safe to always use mode="wb". I argue it the latter should be the default and that the automatic recognition by file extension is faulty and should not be relied upon, cf. https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2012-August/064739.html